# How to convert an Object to a 2D Array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, matrix, methods

Trying to convert my object of type Matrix to an int[][] to produce a matrix with random values. Having trouble with how to do this. Keep getting errors for m2.setMatrixVals([4][3]) such as "illegal start of expression", "not a statement", and "';' expected". Would appreciate any help

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MatrixDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Random r = new Random();
      
      Matrix[][] m1 = new Matrix[4][3];
      Matrix[][] m2 = new Matrix[4][3];
                 
      System.out.println("Matrix A:");
      
      m2.setMatrixVals([4][3]);
      
      for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
      {
         for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
         { 
            matrixVals[i][j] = r.nextInt(20);
            
            System.out.print(matrixVals[i][j] + "\t");
         }
  
         System.out.print("\n");
      }
   }
}
```

Here's my method class:

```
public class Matrix
{
   //instance fields
   private int[][] matrixVals;
   
   public Matrix(int[][] mVals)
   {
      matrixVals = mVals;
   }
   
   public void setMatrixVals(int[][] mVals)
   {   
      matrixVals = mVals;
   }
   
   public int[][] getMatrixVals()
   {
      return matrixVals;
   }
}
```

Having trouble with how to implement the setter into the driver class. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a class `Matrix` which encapsulates a 2-d int array. Yet, in your `main()` method you then proceed to create two 2-d array of `Matrix` objects (`m1` and `m2`), which really doesn't make sense: either you want to encapsulate the 2-d array, or you don't -- which is it?

If you really do want the class `Matrix` which encapsulates a 2-d array with random numbers (makes sense), you should probably do it this way:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class MatrixDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Random r = new Random();

        final Matrix matrix = new Matrix(4, 3);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                matrix.setMatrixValueAt(i, j, r.nextInt(20));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Matrix: \n" + matrix);
    }

    public static class Matrix {
        // instance fields
        private int[][] matrixVals;

        public Matrix(int row, int column) {
            matrixVals = new int[row][column];
        }

        public void setMatrixValueAt(int row, int column, int value) {
            matrixVals[row][column] = value;
        }

        public int[][] getMatrixVals() {
            return matrixVals;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return Arrays.deepToString(matrixVals);
        }
    }

}
```

Note that I declared `Matrix` as `public static`: that's because I want to do everything in a single demo file. If you are developing this further, put `Matrix` in a separate file, `Matrix.java` in the proper package. Remove the `static` keyword in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
int[][] matrixVals = new int[4][3];

for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {

    for(int j=0;j<3;j++) { 

        matrixVals[i][j] = r.nextInt(20);

        System.out.print(matrixVals[i] [j] + "\t");
    }

    System.out.print("\n");
}

m2.setMatrixVals(matrixVals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I might approach it.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
```

The following is pretty straightforward.  I just chose some values to represent key sizes of the `int` array and used a stream to populate it.

```
public class MatrixDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int rows = 4;
        int cols = 3;
        int maxRowVal = 20;
        int maxColVal = 30;
        int[][] vals = r.ints(rows, 1, maxRowVal + 1)
                .mapToObj(rval -> r.ints(cols, 1, maxColVal + 1).toArray())
                .toArray(int[][]::new);
        
        // the following demonstrates the defensive capability. Changing the
        // int array does not alter the Matrix

        for (int[] v : vals) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
        }
        System.out.println("Matrix A:");
        Matrix m2 = new Matrix();
        m2.setMatrixVals(vals);
        vals[2][2] = 1000;
        System.out.println(vals[2][2]);
        for (int[] v : m2.getMatrixVals()) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
        }
    }
}
```

prints something like this.

```
[24, 10, 30]
[7, 20, 8]
[29, 8, 27]
[11, 3, 3]
Matrix A:
1000
[24, 10, 30]
[7, 20, 8]
[29, 8, 27]
[11, 3, 3]
```

The important thing here is to use defensive copying so that if the supplied array is changed outside the class, it won't change the `Matrix array`.  Matrix values should only be altered by setters.  And when retrieving the values, they should be copied again so the returned copy, if modified, won't change the Matrix.

To accomplish the copy I used the `clone()` method.  It has its problems for object cloning but when it comes to primitive arrays it works just fine.

Making defensive copies in the manner may seem expensive but it is considered a good technique and can help prevent unexpected modifications from creeping into your code.

```
class Matrix {
    // instance fields
    private int[][] matrixVals;

    public Matrix() {
       // create an empty Matrix
       // to be populated by using the setMatrixVals method
    }
    
    public Matrix(int[][] mVals) {
        matrixVals = copyValues(mVals);
    }

    public void setMatrixVals(int[][] mVals) {
        matrixVals = copyValues(mVals);
    }

    public int[][] getMatrixVals() {
        return copyValues(matrixVals);
    }
    
    public int getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return matrixVals[row][col];
    }
    
    private int[][] copyValues(int[][] vals) {
        int[][] copy = new int[vals.length][vals[0].length];
        int i = 0;
        for(int[] v : vals) {
            copy[i++] = v.clone();
        }
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Other methods you could add would be

- Create a new matrix from an existing one.  This could be in the form of a set or a different constructor.
- Set a specific element at a row, column location.
- Override `toString()` so that you can print the Object.